# Static member function pointer to hold non static member function

Tags: c++

This has defeated me. I want to have a static class variable which is a pointer to a (non-static) member function. I've tried all sorts of ways, but with no luck (including using `typedef`s, which just seemed to give me a different set of errors). In the code below I have the static class function pointer `funcptr`, and I can call it successfully from outside the class, but not from within the member function `CallFuncptr` - which is what I want to do. Any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A
{
public:
  static int (A::*funcptr)();
  int Four() { return 4;};
  int CallFuncptr() { return (this->*funcptr)(); } 
      // doesn't link -  undefined reference to `A::funcptr'
};
int (A::*funcptr)() = &A::Four;

int main()
{
  A fred;
  printf("four? %d\n", (fred.*funcptr)());  // This works
  printf("four? %d\n", fred.CallFuncptr()); // But this is the way I want to call it
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    typedef int (A::*AMemFn)();
    static AMemFn funcptr;
    int Four() { return 4; }
    int CallFuncptr() { return (this->*funcptr)(); }
};

A::AMemFn A::funcptr = &A::Four;

int main()
{
    A fred;
    std::cout << "four? " << fred.CallFuncptr() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

jweyrich has a nice looking work around (and I suggest you use it), but I thought I'd elaborate on what the real problem in the code is:

Your problem is this line:

```
int (A::*funcptr)() = &A::Four;
```

This is defining a global variable called `funcptr` that is of the right type, rather than `A::funcptr`.

What you need is this mess:

```
int (A::*(A::funcptr))() = &A::Four;
```

This ugly mess is why I suggest you go down the typedef path to get a nice looking version like jweyrich's solution.

Comment: Ah, thanks! ..I was thinking along those lines - just couldn't guess how to attach that second A::. It is indeed a little non obvious..

Answer (score 0):

A static variable is not a member of a particular object -- it can only be accessed through the classes namespace. CallFuncptr should be rewritten:
`int CallFuncptr() { return (*funcptr)();`
which I think should work, since this function can access functions in A's namespace without specifying it.

Also, function pointers are more of a C construct than C++. You can access the static variable outside the class with the code:
`A::CallFuncptr`
since CallFunctptr just resides in A's namespace